# Test GCP publisher retry settings in Spring application

Tags: spring, google-cloud-platform, mockito, spring-integration, integration-testing

I've a spring integration application - which listens for messages from a Kafka topic and publishes them to Google Cloud Topic.

The GCP Publisher is created using DefaultPublisherFactory and has the below retry configuration

```
RetrySettings retrySettings = RetrySettings.newBuilder()
        .setInitialRetryDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .setRetryDelayMultiplier(600)
        .setMaxRetryDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
        .setTotalTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .setInitialRpcTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .setMaxRpcTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .build()
```

The application is up and everything runs as expected.

But I'm unable to figure out how to test the above retry settings.

Since the application isn't failing - the retry scenario is not tested.

I'm fairly new to integration testing - I googled a lot - but could not figure out way - to produce or mock the retry scenario.

Any guidance in figuring this out would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: The code you posted isn't easily testable. You could only test something such as assert the max retry delay is 2 seconds, which probably wouldn't give you confidence in the code. What Mockito can help with is creating a situation where 1 publish fails and the next succeeds and other scenarios like that. Some may argue that is just testing someone else's code such as Spring's or Kafka's, but if it gives you confidence in your code then great. But, for anyone to help you need to post more code.

Comment: Makes sense. The motive behind this was to check - which exception is actually thrown if in case retry fails.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Support here!

As DCTID said, your code is not easily testable, because it will only be run when your application fails. For this reason, I would encourage you to simply wait until that happens - if it ever happens.